# У меня возникает ошибка . Хочу начать делать discord ботов на Python

Tags: python

[image: саблайн]Вот код

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot( command_prefix  =  '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot connect')

@client.command( pass_context = True )

async def hello( ctx ):
    await ctx.send( 'Hello' )

token = open ("text.txt", 'r' ).readline()
client.run( token )
```

и такая ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 15, in <module>
    token = open ("text.txt", 'r' ).readline()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.txt'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

помогите пожалуста
![![папка в которой файл бота
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Jef.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Jef.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так а у вас файл text.txt есть в той папке, в которой вы запускаете bot.py?

Comment: да все в одной папке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас нет файла text.ru в папке вместе с bot.py
Попробуйте вот так.
'w' - открытие на запись, содержимое файла удаляется, если файла не существует, создается новый.
`token = open("text.txt", 'w').readline()`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106059/discussion-on-answer-by-mihailpy--------di).

Answer (score 0):

В разделе

```
token = open("text.txt", 'r').readline()
```

Напиши

```
token = "твой токен"
```

Comment: вероятно, не «в разделе», а «вместо»? в любом случае постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. чтобы исправить/дополнить ответ, нажмите [edit]